# simple password javascript not working

Tags: javascript

```js
function passWord() {
  var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password',' ');
  if (!pass1) {
    window.location.href = ('bad.html');
  }
  else if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "yep") {
    window.location.href = ('webpage.html');
    break;
  } 
  else {
    var pass2 = prompt('Password Incorrect','Password');
    if (!pass2) {
      window.location.href = ('bad.html');
    }
    else if (pass2.toLowerCase() == "yep") {
      window.location.href = ('webpage.html');
      break;
    } 
    else {
      var pass3 = prompt('Incorrect, last try','Password');
      if (!pass3) {
        window.location.href = ('bad.html');
      }
      else if (pass3.toLowerCase() == "yep") {
        window.location.href = ('webpage.html');
        break;
      } 
      else {
        window.location.href = ('bad.html');
      }
    }
  }
}
window.onload = passWord()
```

I am trying to make a script so that it asks for the password three times and if they are all incorrect, it takes you to the "bad" page.
However, the script seems to not work. 
I don't see what is wrong with my code...
Am I just not supposed to have ifs and elses inside an else?

Comment: "not working" doesn't tell us what its actually doing.

Comment: `break` breaks your code. It's used in some loop structures and in `switch`, it is illegal outside of those. You can simply remove the `break`s from your code. The function execution is automatically stopped, when a new page starts to load.'

Comment: I think you wanted return and not break...

Comment: try to look always to you console for the error message

Comment: "not working" means that nothing happens and the code doesn't load

Comment: `break` as well as `return` are completely unnecessary here, as no code follows the if/else statements

Comment: get your logics right :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to switch your `break` statements by `return`. Once you want to leave the method. `break` are used to leave loop blocks.

```js
function passWord() {
  var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password',' ');
  if (!pass1) {
    window.location.href = ('bad.html');
  }
  else if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "yep") {
    window.location.href = ('webpage.html');
    return;
  } 
  else {
    var pass2 = prompt('Password Incorrect','Password');
    if (!pass2) {
      window.location.href = ('bad.html');
    }
    else if (pass2.toLowerCase() == "yep") {
      window.location.href = ('webpage.html');
      return;
    } 
    else {
      var pass3 = prompt('Incorrect, last try','Password');
      if (!pass3) {
        window.location.href = ('bad.html');
      }
      else if (pass3.toLowerCase() == "yep") {
        window.location.href = ('webpage.html');
        return;
      } 
      else {
        window.location.href = ('bad.html');
      }
    }
  }
}
window.onload = passWord()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function passWord() {
    var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password', '');
    if (!pass1) {
        window.location.href = ('bad.html');
    }
    else if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "yep") {
        window.location.href = ('webpage.html');
        return;
    } 
    else {
        var pass2 = prompt('Password Incorrect', 'Password');
        if (!pass2) {
            window.location.href = ('bad.html');
        }
        else if (pass2.toLowerCase() == "yep") {
            window.location.href = ('webpage.html');
            return;
        } 
        else {
            var pass3 = prompt('Incorrect, last try', 'Password');
            if (!pass3) {
                window.location.href = ('bad.html');
            }
            else if (pass3.toLowerCase() == "yep") {
                window.location.href = ('webpage.html');
                return;
            } 
            else {
                window.location.href = ('bad.html');
            }
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    passWord();
}
```

I've lost your indenting here, but the above code has what looks like your desired effect.

The code didn't load because you weren't calling the window.onload function correctly. The conditionals wouldn't have worked correctly after being called, due to the 'break'.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my self, apparently I didn't need any of the break tags.
I deleted them all and my code now works. Thank you to everyone who spent their time answering my question, and i apologise for asking about such a simple mistake